# Cash On Delivery for Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Like all other CMS's Craft Commerce doesn't have a Cash On Delivery payment method by default. How can we add or create a COD method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft Commerce has a COD method called the 'manual' gateway. Make sure you set it to authorize only and it will allow a customer to check out without submitting payment. When cash or cheque is presented you can 'capture' the manual transaction payment on the order edit screen.

Comment: As Luke says, but just rename the payment button to 'Cash On Delivery'. I'm using it for 'Pay BY Invoice' on several sites.